# Improve Performance of Last Occurrence Match in Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I need to find the last occurrence of matches based on an array of acceptable of value. Below is the source codes in Perl. The answer is Q because it is the last occurrence based on acceptable values of A, Q, I & J.

The challenge is how can I change my codes to make the regex faster. It is currently a bottleneck because I have to run it millions times.

```
my $input = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z";
my $regex = qr/(A|Q|I|J)/;

my @matches = $input =~ m/\b$regex\b/g;

print $matches[$#matches];
```

I would like to see new codes that improves the query speed but still can find the Q match.

Comment: `$matches[$#matches]` is usually written `$matches[-1]`

Comment: Additional information: "A" can be a word in real situation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `\K` to discard the previously matched characters from printing at the final.

```
my $input = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z";
my $regex = qr/.*\K\b[AQIJ]\b/;
if ($input =~ m/$regex/) {
print $&."\n";
}
```

Use capturing group.

```
my $input = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z";
my $regex = qr/.*\b([AQIJ])\b/;
if ($input =~ m/$regex/) {
print $1."\n";
}
```

**Update:**

```
my $input = "Apple Orange Mango Apple";
my $regex = qr/.*\K\b(?:Apple|Range|Mango)\b/;
if ($input =~ m/$regex/) {
print $&."\n";
}
```

Comment: A can be a word like APPLE. How can we change the $regex?

Comment: @MichaelC. then you need to use a non-capturing group like `(?:Apple|Orange|.....)` instead of `[AQIJ]`

Comment: Can you please confirm the new code is correct? It looks like it is matching the first Apple (beginning of line), instead of the last Apple (end of line).

Comment: no it matches the last `Apple` string. You may check by changing the above regex to `my $regex = qr/.*\K\b(?:Apple|Range|Mango)\b.*/;` . It must display `Apple` only because there isn't any character after the last `Apple` . `.*` at the first will match all the characters greedily upto the last.

Comment: It is right. I'm evaluating all answers for performance improvement.

Comment: For benchmark purpose, it takes 1 hours 50 minutes to complete original script using this proposed solution.

Comment: Accept a solution which you loves the most.

Comment: I'm still see if there is other answers. I will choose the one yield best performance.

Comment: Ok, it's all upto you.

Comment: @MichaelC.: Making your decision on the basis of a fractional improvement in timing is wrong. If a few minutes in each hour are significant then you need to show your complete program. There are likely to be many more economies made elsewhere than the regular expression

Answer (score 3):

You can find the last match by simply adding a `.*` before the matching pattern.

Like this

```
my $input = "APPLE B C D E F G H INDIGO JACKAL K L M N O P QUIVER R S T U V W X Y Z";
my $regex = qr/APPLE|QUIVER|INDIGO|JACKAL/;
my ($last) = $input =~ /.*\b($regex)\b/;
print $last, "\n";
```

**output**

```
QUIVER
```

Comment: For benchmark purpose, it takes 2 hours 04 minutes to complete original script using this proposed solution.